# Win32 On Mouse Over Event

Tags: button, visual-c++, mouseover

How to know if the cursor on a specific control like a button in Win32? For this purpose WM_MOUSEMOVE exists but I can't get WM_MOUSEMOVE message?

What to do?

Answer (score 1):

There is no `WM_MOUSEOVER`, AFAIK. There is a `WM_MOUSEHOVER`, but that doesn't do what you want. Try `WM_MOUSEMOVE`.

Comment: sorry it was my mistake while writing, yes there is WM_MOUSEMOVE but what to with it to get mouse move event on a button?